# How to pass an object to a handler in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class MenuExampleVerticalPointing extends Component {
  state = { activeItem: 'home' }

  handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state

    return (
      <Menu pointing vertical>
        <Menu.Item name='home' active={activeItem === 'home'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
        <Menu.Item name='messages' active={activeItem === 'messages'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
        <Menu.Item name='friends' active={activeItem === 'friends'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}
```

This is part of the code from Semantic UI. https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu#types-vertical-pointing

How attribute name get passed to the handler here? Why there is an object even there is no object passed to the handler?

Comment: `name` it is a property from your event `e`. When you click on `Menu.Item` you pass event to the method which contains `name` and `active` properties.

Comment: @DenisBubnov But why it show as a second parameter? Can I access it through "event"?

Comment: Yes, you can access it through event, like `e.name` (maybe `e.target.name`). Why second...because to first parameter you need to pass an event. I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How attribute name get passed to the handler here?*

> Destructuring is a convenient way of extracting multiple values
>   from data stored in (possibly nested) objects and Arrays. It can be
>   used in locations that receive data (such as the left-hand side of an
>   assignment).

- Here `name` it is a property from your event `e`. When you click on `Menu.Item` you pass event to the method which contains `name` and `active` properties (or attributes).

---

*Why there is an object even there is no object passed to the handler?*

- Here, `e` is a synthetic event. React defines these synthetic events
  according to the W3C spec, so you don’t need to worry about
  cross-browser compatibility. When you click on the `Menu.Item` then fire an event handler to the specified node. Onclick event always occurs when you click on the specified element.

Links:

- [Destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#_object-destructuring)
- [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)
- [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `onClick` event will be triggered form `Menu.Item`. If you check the `Menu.Item` codes you can see the `onClick` function calling like `this.props.onClick(event, {name : this.props.name})`